# Splash screen comes white on some android devices

Tags: android

In my android application, splash screen comes white in some devices like one plus one and sony xperia z. For many other devices it shows up nicely and the way I want it, but for these two devices it comes as whhite.

What can be the possible reason for this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Which Theme Are You using for Your Activity? Avoid Device Default theme. It May Cause this.

Comment: Kindly give us more details like Xperia and OnePlus running what version of Android, what is your minimum and compiling SDK versions and post code like `build.gradle`, various `styles.xml`! So we can help!

Comment: Hi, the both devices you are talking about have 1920x1080 display, did you create splashscreen adapted to them ? I'm working on iOS and we need a different splash screen by resolution

Comment: hey guys, both are on lollipop 5.1; parent theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar. Minimum sdk version is 16 and compile sdk version is 22